# Matplotlib - Sharex with different ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say one has 2 subplots, one on top of the other. 
Let's also assume the upper plots xrange runs from 0-30 and lower plots xrange runs from 0-1. Both plots have to zoom in and out simultaneously so sharex is required.

Is there a way I can use sharex with a scaling factor/function such as x_upper=x_lower*30 or something similar?

PS: My question is very similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262669/matplotlib-shared-axis-scales-with-different-limits) but the code given the answer has a class pix_to_fig which is nowhere to be found.